# How filebeat custom parse rules?

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I have a project, it output's log is very special. like:

```
===============table_tiltle=====================
                                    |   TOTAL|    FAIL| FailNor| FailErr|  SUMVAL|  AVG(ms)|  MAX(ms)|  MIN(ms)|    >2ms|   >10ms|   >50ms|  >100ms|MAX_RECORD           |
name1.                              |      12|       0|       0|       0|       0| 0.009333|    0.012|    0.007|       0|       0|       0|       0|                     |
name2                               |      12|       0|       0|       0|       0| 0.131917|    0.157|    0.108|       0|       0|       0|       0|                     |
name3                               |      12|       0|       0|       0|       0| 0.140667|    0.167|    0.117|       0|       0|       0|       0|                     |
name4.                              |      12|       0|       0|       0|       0| 0.140833|    0.167|    0.117|       0|       0|       0|       0|                     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------
ALL                                 | xxx    | xxx    | xxx    | ...
```

It looks like a database table. i want to parse it in filebeat by myself parser or other way?

I expect someone can give me some help for this? like docs link or other.

Comment: Can you show what you have tried ?
Maybe with this input ? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/decode-csv-fields.html

Comment: In fact this log is not very simple. I update the log format.

Comment: Did you try dissect processor ? Combined with regex condition, it should work.